# Instance of 'OneToOneField' has no 'username' member

Tags: python, django

I got the following error when I created Profile model

> Instance of 'OneToOneField' has no 'username' member

This is the snippet of the code I created

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg", upload_to="profile_pics")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username} Profile"
```

previously it was working fine. Now, all of a sudden I am getting this error.I didn't understand the meaning of this error.  How do I solve it? 
Thank you

Comment: Where you are getting error? If it is in `self.user.username`, then i guess you are getting a warning in vs code. That will work fine when you runserver despite error. If not in that then you should show the whole error message.

Comment: so you get this error after you make Profile model or suddenly you start getting this error

Comment: When I run server in terminal I get no errors
 (System check identified no issues (0 silenced)
but in vscode it shows this error! what is the problem here?

Answer (score 6):

In order for pylint to work properly with Django you should install the `pylint-django` packege:

```
pip install pylint-django
```

Then you can run `pylint` with `pylint_django` as a plugin:

```
pylint --load-plugins pylint_django <path_to_django_file>
```

If you are using VSCode as your IDE, you can add this snippet to your `.vscode/settings.json` file to load the plugin for your project:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins",
        "pylint_django"
    ]
}
```

Or, if you have a `.pylintrc` file, you can add this line to load the plugin:

```
[MASTER]
load-plugins=pylint_django
```

[You can find out more on about `pylint-django` here.](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django#features)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Pumi's answer, when you pip install pylint-django, you may likely have another error:
"ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'wrapt'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall."

Then you have to type this:

```sh
pip install wrapt --upgrade --ignore-installed
```

And re-try `pip install pylint-django`

Also inside the `.vscode/settings.json`, there's an existing `{"python.pythonPath": "./anaconda3/bin/python"}` if you are using conda interpreter. So you only need to add the list without additional curly brackets as specified  @Pumi. So you will have something like this:

```
{
"python.pythonPath": "./anaconda3/bin/python",

"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins",
        "pylint_django"
    ]
}
```

Then you're good to go.