# Problem getting "first_name" and "last_name" from User model

Tags: django

I'm creating the Client model like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from platforms.models import Platform

class Client(models.Model):
    """Model definition for Client."""

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.CharField(("Compañía"), max_length=50)
    platforms = models.ManyToManyField(Platform, verbose_name=("Plataformas"))

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for Client."""

        verbose_name = 'Cliente'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Clientes'

    def __str__(self):
        """Representación de cliente."""

        company = "Sin empresa"
        if self.company:
            company = self.company

        string = "{} {} ({})".format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name, company)

        return string
```

But in this part, when I try to get the first_name and user_name I get an error:

```
string = "{} {} ({})".format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name, company)
```

This is the error:

```
Instance of 'OneToOneField' has no 'first_name' member
```

Why does this happen? "User" model should have first_name and last_name right?

Thank you?

Comment: Yes. Django's user model does have first_name and last_name. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204906/instance-of-onetoonefield-has-no-username-member) solve your issue?

Comment: Oh nice! I don't get those errors now. Thank you.